# Is there any way to convert (list 1 2 3) to just 1 2 3 in Racket(Scheme)?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/parse/define)
(require racket/draw)

(define thickness 1.99)

(define color-set 
  (hash
   `black `(0 0 0)
   `white `(255 255 255)
   `light-grey `(229 229 229)
   `dark-grey `(153 153 153)))

(define font-set
  (hash
    `default (make-font #:size 17 #:family 'script #:weight '550 #:smoothing `smoothed) 
    `index (make-font #:size 11 #:family 'modern #:weight '400 #:smoothing `smoothed)
    `comment (make-font #:size 11 #:family 'modern #:weight '400 #:smoothing `smoothed)))


(define-syntax-parser grab
  #:datum-literals (pen brush font)

  [(_ pen color alpha)
   (send dc set-pen (make-color ,@(hash-ref color-set (quasiquote color)) alpha))]

  [(_ pen color)
   (send dc set-pen (make-color ,@(hash-ref color-set (quasiquote color)) 1))]

  [(_ brush color style)
   (send dc set-brush (make-color ,@(hash-ref color-set (quasiquote color)) alpha) (quasiquote style))]

  [(_ brush color)
   (send dc set-brush (make-color ,@(hash-ref color-set (quasiquote color)) alpha) 'solid)]

  [(_ font mode)
   (send dc set-font (hash-ref font-set (quasiquote mode)))])
```

This question is about basic racket macro.
I am making something with racket/draw.
and I want to make my own grab function to make set-pen, set-font, set-brush more intuitive.
But I encountered a problem.

what I was trying to do is,
with `(make-color ,@(hash-ref color-set (quasiquote color)) 1)`,
I want to create `(make-color 255 255 255 1)`.  (If color is black)

but I got error message : 
`unquote-splicing: not in quasiquote in: (unquote-splicing (hash-ref color-set (quasiquote color)))`

It seems like `,@` can only be used to `(list 1 @,(list 1 2 3) 2 3)`. not for `(list 255 255 255)` to `255 255 255`.

What can I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters most of the time you should be using quotes, not quasiquotes. For example:

```
(define color-set 
  (hash
   'black '(0 0 0)
   'white '(255 255 255)
   'light-grey '(229 229 229)
   'dark-grey '(153 153 153)))
```

It's simple to do what you want without resorting to quasiquoting, we just need to build the parameter list as required and `apply` the procedure:

```
(apply make-color (append (hash-ref color-set color) (list 1)))
```

In principle we *could* use quasiquoting and list splicing to do what you intend, but then we have to remember that when we quasiquote a list we're dealing with a list of *symbols*, and they need to be evaluated to be meaningful, and that's when things get ugly:

```
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))
(eval `(make-color ,@(hash-ref color-set color) 1) ns)
```